# Callbacks on SynchronizationContext

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windowsformshost

Trying to wrap my head around why a windows Form implementing a callback is not working.

What I'm trying to do:

- A button is pressed and a service is called.
- The service calls back to the form (the function has IsOneWay = true)
- The form updates GUI accordingly

Having UseSynchronizationContext on false and calling Invoke on the GUI members works fine:

```
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class DeliveryClient : System.Windows.Forms.Form, ICallback
{        
        public void ServiceCallback(string system, string state, string extraInfo)
        {
            if (state == "start")
            {
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { picBox.Visible = true; });
            }
            else
            {
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { picBox.Visible = false; });
            }
        }
}
```

But UseSynchronizationContext = true and directly calling the members does not:

```
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = true)]
public class DeliveryClient : System.Windows.Forms.Form, ICallback
{        
        public void ServiceCallback(string system, string state, string extraInfo)
        {
            if (state == "start")
            {
                picBox.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                picBox.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Neither does using SyynchronizationContext literally

```
SynchronizationContext.Current.Send(_=> picBox.Visible = true, null);
```

Should the second and third version also work? The callback is called OneWay so the service continues after callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your `Form` class *really* the implementation of your WCF service client callback, *as WCF knows it* (i.e. not just something you delegate to from the WCF client)? If not, then you've put the `[CallbackBehavior]` attribute in the wrong place. As the documentation states:

> The CallbackBehaviorAttribute must be applied to the class that implements the callback contract

If it is the implementation of your client callback, then without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I'm afraid I wouldn't be able to say why the attribute isn't having the expected effect. But I *would* be able to say that, if that is indeed the case, your code is designed poorly. Combining your UI with your service client callback implementation violates a number of OOP principles for healthy code, but most importantly the [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle.

As far as this goes:

```
SynchronizationContext.Current.Send(_=> picBox.Visible = true, null);
```

That's not how you should use `SynchronizationContext`. The `Current` property returns the context for the currently running thread. By the time you need to call `Send()`, it's too late to retrieve the context. You need to store `SynchronizationContext.Current` when you create your object, in the thread where you want delegates invoked by `Send()` to be executed (and of course, that thread has to have a useful context, such as found in the main UI thread of a Winforms program).

If the above does not give you enough information to get your code working, please improve the question by providing a good MCVE that reliably reproduces the problem.